# jQuery: hide multi-depth all DIVs, then show one

Tags: jquery, html, css, children, siblings

I have some simple markup to draw a drop-down menu and a few divs of varying complexity:

```
<select class='sel'>
    <option data-opt='a'>show only 'a' boxes</option>
    <option data-opt='b'>show only 'b' boxes</option>
    <option data-opt='*'>show all</option>
</select>

<div class='holder'>
    <div class='a'>
        <div>
            <p>Here is some text (A)</p>
        </div>
        <p>Plus more stuff in here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class='a'>
        <p>More text (A)</p>
    </div>
    <div class='b'>
        <p>Here is other text (B)</p>
        <div><span>There is more in here!</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class='b'>
        <p>Even more text (B)</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And when the user chooses an option from the drop-down, I want to hide the DIVs that don't match, and only show the DIVs that match:

```
$('.sel').change(function() {
    opt = $(this).find(":selected").data('opt');
    console.log('option chosen: '+opt);

    if(opt == '*') { // select all
        console.log('show all');
        $('.holder').show();

    } else { // hide all but this
        $('.holder :not(div'+opt+')').hide();
        $('.holder').find('div'+opt).show();

    }
});
```

However, for some reason it's not working. It looks like the hide() method is hiding every element (including the children/siblings of the main DIVs), and then the show() method is only showing the initial DIV. And the show-all option isn't working at all. So there are some issues with depth. How can I fix this?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pnoeric/FjEBY/3/

Comment: Don't forget to pick the answer of what you use :)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/FjEBY/6/ is the answer.

Your selectors were a bit off and you forgot a `.` before the `opt` bit.

```
$('.sel').change(function() {

    var opt = $(this).find(":selected").data('opt'),
        all = $('.holder').children('div').show();

    if ( opt !== '*' ) {
      all.not('.' + opt).hide();   
    }

});
```

Comment: I need to tweak mine one sec I didn't realize I was missing a sentence in one of the boxes

Comment: Combined Tushar's and mine to make a simpler block

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/FjEBY/5/)

```
$('.sel').change(function () {
    opt = $(this).find(":selected").data('opt');
    console.log('option chosen: ' + opt);
    if (opt == '*') { // select all
        $('.holder').children('div').show()
    } else { // hide all but this
        $('.holder').children('div').show().not('.' + opt).hide();
    }
});
```

Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the `.find()` method allows us to search through the descendants of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements. The `.find()` and `.children()` methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level down the DOM tree.

So it's better if you use `.children()` here

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/FjEBY/7/)

```
var holder = $('.holder').children('div');
$('.sel').change(function () {
    opt = $(this).find(":selected").data('opt');
    console.log('option chosen: ' + opt);
    if (opt == '*') { // select all
        holder.show()
    } else { // hide all but this
        holder.show().not('.' + opt).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: @Eric this code is faster than yours. As you are using .`find()` but your purpose can be served with `.children()` see this image --> http://tinyurl.com/2clyrbz